# Why do I get ImportError of xlwings when running RunPython from Excel on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, excel, xlwings, vba

I am trying to run a Python script from `Excel 2016` on Mac. When I run the code nothing happens, and the status bar in `Excel` gets stuck on "Running". I have checked the `xlwings log file` and I can see that the `error` is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/Users/dano/Desktop/hello.py", line 3, in
>
> import xlwings as xw
>
> ImportError: No module named xlwings

However when I import `xlwings` from a Python shell it works fine, and I have also managed to write to the active workbook from the Python Shell using `xlwings`. Why does it say that there is no module named `xlwings`when I clearly have it installed?

I am using the simple `hello.py` example from the `xlwings` documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
def world():
  wb = xw.Book.caller()
  wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = 'Hello World!'
```

The `.py file` and the `excel file` are located on my Desktop. I am running `Python 3.6` and have installed `xlwings` using `pip3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlwings takes the default Python installation as defined in your `.bash_profile` file, see the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-settings).

That is, you either need to include python3 in your PATH (given that you used pip3) or you need to set the Python interpreter via xlwings.

To set it in your `.bash_profile`, you would do something like:

```
export PATH="/path/to/python3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My current `.bash_profile` is the following:
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH`

This seems to be according to your suggestion. It still doesn't work however. Do I need to set a specific path to the interpreter in the `.config file`? The `xlwings` module is located in the same directory as given in the PATH above.

Comment: when you open a terminal window, enter `python` in it and then try to import xlwings, does it work?

Comment: No, since I am using python 3.6. But if I write python3 in the terminal and import xlwings it works, as I stated in my question.

Comment: You need to tweak your `.bash_profile` so that `python` starts `python3` or you need to specify the full path to python3 in the xlwings config

Comment: How would I do that? I tried to change the xlwings config for the interpreter to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` but that gave me the error `sh: line 1: -B: command not found`.

Comment: UPDATE: It now works with the path specified above. It was an error in the type of quotation marks that caused the error. It needs to be the straight quotation marks that are default in the `.config file`.